# Status bar being overlapped by my app screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

As you can see in the below screenshot, the status bar on iPhone is getting overlapped by my app screen, thereby making the clock, signal and battery appear opaque.

[image]

Below is the code for the same:

```
return Container(
          child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: buildUnAuthenticatedBottomNavigationBar(context),
          body: SafeArea(child: unAuthenticatedScreens[selectedIndex]),
         ),
        );
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Wrap SafeArea to Scaffoldnot to body

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return SafeArea(
  top: false,
  child: Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: buildUnAuthenticatedBottomNavigationBar(context),
    body: unAuthenticatedScreens[selectedIndex]),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: buildUnAuthenticatedBottomNavigationBar(context),
          body: unAuthenticatedScreens[selectedIndex]),
         ),
        )
```